How can I make perf find symbols in my golang program
I want to use perf and FlameGraph to generate a cpu usage flamegraph of my golang program.
$ go build -gcflags=all="-N -l" -o my_program ./*.go # Compile with debug info.
$ ./my_program
$ perf record -e cycles -F 100 --call-graph dwarf,65528 -o ~/my.data -p <my_program pid>
$ perf script -i ~/my.data | ~/FlameGraph/stackcollapse-perf.pl | ~/FlameGraph/flamegraph.pl > ~/perf.svg

In the flamegraph, all the functions in my program has the name [my_program], and I can't see their real names. Here are some outputs of perf report -i ~/my.data --stdio:
Warning:                                                                                                                              
Processed 3832 events and lost 1 chunks!                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                      
Check IO/CPU overload!                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                      
# To display the perf.data header info, please use --header/--header-only options.                                                    
#                                                                                                                                     
#                                                                                                                                     
# Total Lost Samples: 0                                                                                                               
#                                                                                                                                     
# Samples: 219  of event 'cycles'                                                                                                     
# Event count (approx.): 763795261                                                                                                    
#                                                                                                                                     
# Children      Self  Command          Shared Object        Symbol                                                                    
                                                                                                                                      
# ........  ........  ...............  ...................  ..........................................................................
...............................................................................................................................       
#                                                                                                                                     
    54.10%    10.45%  my_program       my_program           [.] _start                                                                
            |                                                                                                                         
            |--43.65%--_start                                                                                                         
            |          |                                  

......
            |                     |                                                                                                   
            |                      --3.84%--_start                                                                                    
            |   
             --3.64%--0x188a20
                       0x703797
                       0x7075a4
                       0x707a88
                       0x6fe2f0
                       0x257273
                       0x258e8b
                       0x266945
                       0x2673ec
                       0x260fcb
                       0x2675c6
                       0x210c04
                       0x217b90
                       0x218b24
                       _start
                       _start
                       _start

......

I tried to use go build -toolexec="perf record" my_program, but it doesn't work.
Thanks for your time!
Update
An alternative solution is to use pprof to profile the cpu usage and generate the flamegraph. But I still want to know how to make perf find the symbols in the program.
